# Registrar dato una vez al mes (Php mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicacion php con Codeigniter y mysql. 
Y tengo una tabla cualquiera en la que se debe hacer un insert sola una vez al mes, o sea si hasta el dia de hoy no se ha registrado nada debe dejarme hacer el insert, de lo contrario no debe dejar sino hasta el primer dia del proximo mes.

alguna idea de como hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con una consulta

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tu_tabla WHERE MONTH(tu_fecha) = MONTH(NOW());
```

Si tienes tu modelo  puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tu_tabla');
 $this->db->where('MONTH(tu_fecha)', 'MONTH(NOW())');
 $query = $this->db->get();

if(empty($query->result())){
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

Si te regresa vacio, en php permites el registro, si te regresa datos no permites el INSERT, esto se haría con un IF, este ya depende de como lo estés programando

Comment: gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba